# Set Grid layout as default in Google Keep

Tags: google-keep

I just started using the Google Keep service and I have noticed that the web-interface always starts in the list-view, even if I set it to grid.

Is there a way to configure Google Keep to always use the grid layout on the web-interface?

(I am using the latest stable Google Chrome, the Android app works fine.)

Comment: Things have now changed (end of 2015)... the layout in the web-interface stays on whichever was chosen last: grid or list view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been doing a deep dive on Keep and have yet to find any documentation.

To your specific question, I am not aware of any options that enables you to set any preferences related to default display of Notes such as Grid or List.

No Settings
No Preferences

nada

Comment: There's not even a formal way to get to Keep on the web. I expect that there will be some actual options one can adjust when the Drive team gets around to pushing out their changes.

Comment: Well then, thank you for your efforts. I hope that there will be permanent settings when Keep is properly included in the drive.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Google Keep now persists the selected view setting across sessions.

Setting it to list or grid and reloading the page or creating new windows continues with the same view style.